# Email notification after account is created

Tags: email, workflow, notification

I am trying to make a workflow rule that will send an email to that specific sales person after an account is created.

What i am doing to accomplish this is setting a Rule Criteria after the account is created with the Field (multiselect picklist) Contacted by is set with that Sales Person.

During that process I am getting this Error: This type of field (Picklist (Multi-Select)) cannot use the selected operator.

Please advise how can i solve this or any idea if possible.

Thanks,

Darko

Answer (score 2):

Please use INCLUDES() function in the formula for Multi Select picklist fields.

```
INCLUDES(Hobbies__c, "Golf")
```

Please refer the following link for more details :

1. https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=tips_for_using_picklist_formula_fields.htm&language=en_US
2. https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&language=en_US#INCLUDES